# Freeing last element of a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, delete-operator

I have

```
int * array=new int[2];
```

and I would like to **free the memory of the last element**, thus reducing the allocated memory to only 1 element. I tried to call

```
delete array+1;
```

but it gives error

> *** glibc detected *** skuska:
>   free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000065a020 ***

Can this be done in C++03 without explicit reallocation?

Note: If I wanted to use a class instead a primitive datatype (like int), how can I free the memory so that the destructor of the class is called too?

Note2: I am trying to implement `vector::pop_back`

Comment: Why can't you just use `vector::pop_back`? Re-inventing the wheel is going to cause you more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I am trying to implement a vector-like class myself as a programming exercise and now I am implementing `vector::pop_back`. I used `int* p_array_of_values` as underlying data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `new[]` expression for this.  That's not how vector works.  What you do is allocate a chunk of raw memory.  You could use malloc for this, or you could use [operator new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), which is different from the new expression.  This is essentially what the `reserve()` member function of `std::vector` does, assuming you've used the default allocator.  It doesn't create any actual objects the way the `new[]` expression does.

When you want to construct an element, you use [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), passing it a location somewhere in the raw memory you've allocated.  When you want to destoy an element, you call its destructor directly.  When you are done, instead of using the `delete[]` expression, you use `operator delete` if you used `operator new`, or you use `free()` if you used `malloc`.

Here's an example creating 10 objects, and destoying them in reverse order. I could destroy them in any order, but this is how you would do it in a vector implementation.

```
int main()
{
    void * storage = malloc(sizeof(MyClass) * 10);

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        // this is placement new
       new ((MyClass*)storage + i) MyClass;
    }

    for (int i=9; i>=0; --i)
    {
        // calling the destructor directly
        ((MyClass*)storage + i)->~MyClass();
    }

    free(storage);
}
```

`pop_back` would be implemented by simply calling the destructor of the last element, and decrementing the size member variable by 1.  It wouldn't, shouldn't (and couldn't, without making a bunch of unnecessary copies) free any memory.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such option. Only way to resize array is allocate new array with size `old_size - 1`, copy content of old array and then delete old array.

If you want free object memory why not create array of pointers?

```
MyClass **arr = new MyClass*[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 arr[i] = new MyClass;

// ...

delete arr[size-1];
```

Comment: That is an option, but I already used I used `int* p_array_of_values` as the underlying data structure. Anyway, I have found some nice solutions here already.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector::pop_back` doesn't reallocate anything — it simply updates the internal variable determining data size, reducing it by one. The old last element is still there in memory; the vector simply doesn't let you access it through its public API. *

This, as well as *growing* re-allocation being non-linear, is the basis of why `std::vector::capacity()` is not equivalent to `std::vector::size()`.

So, if you're really trying to re-invent `std::vector` for whatever reason, the answer to your question about re-allocation is *don't*.

---

* Actually for non-primitive data types it's a little more complex, since such elements *are* semantically destroyed even though their memory will not be freed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++03, you have access to the `std::vector` data type. Use that and it's one call:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<int> ary(3);
//...
ary.erase(ary.begin() + (ary.size() - 1));
```

or

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<int> ary(3);
//...
ary.pop_back();
```

## EDIT:

Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel? Just use vector::pop_back.

Anyway, the destructor is called on contained data types ONLY if the contained data type IS NOT a pointer. If it IS a pointer you must manually call delete on the object you want to delete, set it to `nullptr` or `NULL` (because attempting to call delete on a previously deleted object is bad, calling delete on a null pointer is a non-op), then call erase.