# Computional complexity of sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Currently, I am doing a project for my university, where I do implement known data structures (array, linked list, BST, etc.) and I have to measure the times some operations on them require. For example, the first one for me was array. I've measured the time for adding an element in the middle of an array (with moving further values ofc, so `n = n + 1`. It of course gave me `O(n)`, where n is a number of elements. Now I have to check for adding an element to the beginning of array and appending an element to it (adding to the end). I've got 2 simple algorithms (I cannot use `STL` or `boost::`):

Adding to the beginning:

```
void array::beginning_append(int value)
{   
    int *temp = new int[n + 1];
    memcpy(temp + 1, table, sizeof(int) * n);
    n = n + 1;
    temp[0] = value;
    delete[] table;
    table = new int[n];
    memcpy(table, temp, sizeof(int) * n);
    delete[] temp;
}
```

Appending to the end:

```
void array::append(int value)
{
    int *temp = new int[n + 1];
    memcpy(temp, table, sizeof(int) * n);
    temp[n] = value;
    n = n + 1;
    delete[] table;
    table = new int[n];
    memcpy(table, temp, sizeof(int) * n);
    delete[] temp;
}
```

Those are methods or `array` class, where `table` and `n` are members of this class. Now those do not differ that much, I thought their times will be the same, and they are (I checked with `QueryPerformanceCounter` for big numbers of elements, like `500000`, and it gave me `O(n)` complexity), but my lecturer said that adding to beginning will have `O(n)` computational complexity, but adding or removing an element from the end will have complexity of `O(1)`, so it will be const, no matter of the number of elements. So I would like to ask you guys if my algorithms are bad, I mean they do unnecessary stuff, and that's why they rely on number of elements, or my lecturer was just wrong

Comment: prepend instead of begging append? :)

Comment: I prolly should do that :D When I'm coding, my ability to speak, or write proper english decreases, so f.e I write `beggining` instead of `beginning`

Comment: The times don't differ because in both cases you are reallocating and copying the entire array.  If you want to understand why appending to the end is constant, read up about _amortized constant time_

Comment: @paddy, yes I know. But I have to do that, how can I remove an element without shrinking the array?

Comment: Who says you need to shrink the array?

Comment: You can decrease the `n`

Comment: But then I have something stupid in memory

Comment: Welcome to programming.

Comment: Prolly my computers architecture lab guy would kill me if I would leave something unused in memory :D

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215645/freeing-last-element-of-a-dynamic-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both complexities are:

> O(n)

because you are copying the entire array.

See more about complexity of `memcpy()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362760/how-do-realloc-and-memcpy-work).

---

Tip: You could easily skip the second copy, by freeing the memory `table` is pointing to, and then making it point `temp`. That way you will copy only once, not twice. However, the overall time complexity will not change.

Example:

```
void array::prepend(int value)
{   
    int *temp = new int[n + 1];
    memcpy(temp + 1, table, sizeof(int) * n);
    n = n + 1;
    temp[0] = value;
    delete[] table;
    table = temp;
}
```

---

Pro tip: [How do you detect/avoid Memory leaks in your (Unmanaged) code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627/how-do-you-detect-avoid-memory-leaks-in-your-unmanaged-code)

<sub>Hunch: A clever implementation of `realloc()` should execute faster than a brute `memcpy()` to a new array. The reason is that if `realloc()` is able to grow/shrink your array without having to copy the whole thing into a new location (which can occur when there is simple not enough contiguous space), then it will be faster. `realloc()` does not mean O(1) always.</sub>

Comment: There is this line: `n = n+1`

Comment: Point is: why you copy the array twice? Just make table point temp

Comment: Yes, i know, thats right. I didn't use `cpp` for a long time and I was curious if I make table point to temp, then I have to delete[] temp, or not, but now I think I don't :D Am I correct?

Comment: @Frynio memory that has been dynamically allocated *must* be deallocated by you, see my updated answer please.

Comment: I know, I did `delete[] table` and then `table = temp`, I guess that's ok, right?

Comment: Yeah, but the order matters. First delete then assign the pointer elsewhere, otherwise you will leave the initial memory allocated "forever" @Frynio!

Comment: So I did this: (after `temp[0] = value`), `delete[] table;`, `table = temp;` and thats it. Im just scared of memory leaks. Is there any? :D

Comment: Yeah @Frynio, just like my example I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the end can be achieved in `O(1)` when the buffer is big enough to hold the new element. Usually, when a reallocation is done, the memory size is increased by more than what is needed at the moment, to not have to do reallocations too often.

In this case you would have an average complexity of `O(1)` and a worst-time complexity of `O(n)` when a reallocation occurs.

Comment: I do have to allocate the table dynamically, and the size has to be just as big as the number of elements is

Comment: The stl `vector` for example has a `size` and `capacity` member, `size` is of course always exact.

Comment: Not to mention [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit)

Comment: If you can use C style memory management, using realloc() can make you speed up allocation, and let the append be O(1).

Comment: @paddy (s)he cannot use STL.

Comment: I am aware of this.  I am simply illustrating that is there for a reason.

Comment: @Jack, but can I use `realloc()` if I didn't use `malloc()` before?

Comment: @Frynio afaik no. You can only user new/delete (c++ style) or malloc(/realloc/calloc)/free (c style)

Comment: Okay, I checked that. It works (with `realloc()`). And its `O(1)`

Comment: Oops. I guess it doesn't. I mean you prolly were correct, I can't mix `realloc` with `new/delete`. Hmm. @Edit, okay, I was stupid, I only did `realloc()`, wher I should do `table = (int*)realloc()`, now it works